Using free with pointer to middle of allocation
I have recently come across C devs recommending use cases for calling the free(void*) function, but instead of passing the original pointer returned by malloc, passing a pointer to another address which is in the middle of the original allocated block of memory.
Is this ANSI C? Where is this behavior specified? Is it portable to any compliant compiler?
Edit: FYI, the context this was presented in was in implementing BStrings, where the length of the string is stored before the pointer address, and the data is stored after. It was claimed you can free the pointer as is, which did not sound right to me.

imo thats UB, nowhere to lookup the size

No. It is broken for any compiler. realloc() is the only thing that can resize an existing (malloc/calloc) allocation and it, like free(), requires the original pointer value.

Nope. You can only free a pointer that was returned by malloc() or calloc() or realloc(). If you want to resize a memory allocation, use realloc, although any self-referencing pointer will be broken if the memory block is moved to a different location.

The official realloc() with an argument of half the originally allocated buffer size, say, would have the same effect as the proposed hack, so there's no point.

Re “ I have recently come across C devs recommending…”: Where?

@EricPostpischil I do not think it is a genuine question

Please provide more info on who/where/how that recommendation was made. Ideally link to the source. Otherwise quote.

The only place I could see this working is if you have a dynamically allocated array of pointers, and each represents a dynamically allocated block of memory. Then a pointer at the middle of the array could be freed.

Did your read the documentation of free, especially the third paragraph?

@jabberwocky, I did read the documentation, but the source I read from was worded a bit differently. The undefined behavior part said something like UB is triggered if the pointer is not pointing at memory allocated by malloc, which is much more ambiguous.

@RichRemer burn that book

The C standard (C11) says:

7.22.3.3 The free function
Synopsis
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void free(void *ptr);

Description
The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.

The verbiage of C23 is the same.
So, the standard explicitly says that the behaviour is undefined.  Most implementations do not handle pointers to the middle of an allocated block.  There is no defined way for free() to report an 'invalid argument' error as it returns no value.  Any implementation that does handle such erroneous calls to free() is not required to do so by the standard.

Doing so is invalid and will cause undefined behavior.
The only pointer value that can be passed to free is one previously returned by malloc, calloc, or realloc, or NULL.  This is dictated in section 7.22.3.3 of the C standard regarding the free function:

The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or
if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
behavior is undefined.

